# automic uc4 - email script fired off unexpectedly

Tags: uc4, automic

In my UC4 work flow, I set up an email script, to email the team the completion of job. This script is set up on a dependency on 'ANY-OK' of a previous job.

However, the email script was always fired off in the beginning of the workflow, instead of the end/ When I open the job monitor, while previous jobs were still running, the email script shows as status - 'waiting for pre-predecessor' .

So how the email was sent when the email script is still 'waiting for pre-predecessor'?

Answer (score 0):

two remarks:

1. is the "generate at runtime" flag set - otherwise this might be set up during generation time
2. is the mail-job started from somewhere else (different workflow, different schedule, via script command uc_activate_object, etc.) - if so and the information of recipient, message is "hardcoded" you will get the mail regardless if reached in the workflow. Check in the statistic-records, when and from which parent it was started

Answer (score 0):

When we set up jobs in automic, our dependencies are set to the previous object completing with the 'all states must match' circle checked. Then we have an ELSE 'block. Some people have funky pre or postconditions. Also, it's not uncommon for yet another workflow to kick off another object within another job, which is also super fun to chase down. Automic compared to it's previous iteration Appworx is quite different, and sometimes not in a good way :)